# Iterate Object Keys to Arrays in React/ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wanted to iterate the keys and values to be an array in es6 or react.
Pls check my code below:

```
const newData = {
    "id": 111,
    "name": "ewfwef",
    "description": "Hello"
}

const data = Object.keys(newData).forEach((item) => {console.log("item", newData[item])})
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
[
  {
    key: id,
    value: 111
  }, 
  {
    key: name,
    value: 'ewfef'
  },
  {
    key: description,
    value: 'Hello'
  }
]
```

Comment: Asking the [same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084385/iterate-object-keys-in-es6-and-react) (with less information) because the other was closed doesn't make the question any better...

Comment: React isn't relevant here; and your callback function logs the literal string `"item"` instead of the `item` variable's value.

Comment: you can use declarative syntax: `Object.keys(newData).map(item => [{item, newData[item]}])`

Comment: `const data = Object.entries(newData).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired result

```js
const newData = {
  id: 111,
  name: "ewfwef",
  description: "Hello",
};

const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));

console.log(data);
```

You can add two keys in two ways:

**1)** If you don't want to change the resulting array then you can push elements in the array

```js
const newData = {
  id: 111,
  name: "ewfwef",
  description: "Hello",
};

const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));
data.push({ key: "day", value: "monday" });
data.push({ key: "week", value: "7th" });

console.log(data);
```

**2)** Or you can both `key-value` in the source object

```js
const newData = {
  id: 111,
  name: "ewfwef",
  description: "Hello",
  day: "monday",
  week: "7th",
};

const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: _"Instead of..."_ - Or just close it as an obvious dupe.

Comment: Thank you, on top of that, how do you a static key value pair if you want? Thanks\

Comment: what do you mean by static `key-value` pair

Comment: Let's say you want to add  this  `{day: 'Monday', week: '7th'}` on that on this `Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));` ?

Comment: where do you want to add? In the result array? If yes then you need to specify the position because result is an array.

Comment: Inside this one `Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));`. Just put on the last parts

Comment: I'm not able to understand, Would you please add desired result as code.

Comment: Can we do like this? I want to add this like this `Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }, {day: 'Monday', week: '7th'}));`

Comment: Value should be same thing `[
  {
    key: id,
    value: 111
  }, 
  {
    key: name,
    value: 'ewfef'
  },
  {
    key: description,
    value: 'Hello'
  },
{
    key: day,
    value: 'monday'
  },
  {
      key: week,
      value: '7th'
  }
]`

Comment: You can but the result that you will get is may not be what you want. Do you want to add `day` and `week` property in all objects?

Comment: As `result` object is an array then you can push any  number of object like `data.push({ key: "day", value: "monday" });`

Comment: I want to add together thats why I do like this `Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }, {day: 'Monday', week: '7th'}));` How would you do it?

Comment: You can do this. If you do this then you will get 3 objects in an array exactly same as `{day: 'Monday', week: '7th'}`

Comment: No, i don't like 3 objects in the array. I wanted it like this https://pasteboard.co/KjtRvP3.png

Comment: Then you have to push the last 2 objects manually, If your dataset doesn't change...

Comment: How do i do it? I wanted one code only. Can you include on this one? `Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` and `map` to achieve this,

```
  const newData = {
        "id": 111,
        "name": "ewfwef",
        "description": "Hello"
    }
    
    const data = Object.entries(newData).map(function(item) {
      return {key: item[0], value: item[1]};
    });
    
    console.log(data)
```